# How to solve a equation set in python?

Tags: python

I want to solve a equation set like this in python

```
0 + x01 + 0 + x03 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 = 5
0 + 0 + 0 + 0 - x01 - 0 - 0 - 0 = -4
0 + 0 + 0 + x23 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 = 5
0 + 0 + 0 + 0 - x03 - 0 - x23 - 0 = -6
```

If there is a feasible solution, print all x
If there is no solution, print 'no solution'

Thanks!

Comment: What are you having problems with?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789927/is-there-a-python-module-to-solve-linear-equations unless you want to program an algorithm yourself? Then I'd start with something like the Gauss algorithm and show us what doesn't work

Comment: Take a look at `numpy.linalg`?

Comment: Look up linear algebra and Gaussian reduction. It uses matrices, which are easy to code with. You have to parse your lines to create the matrices you need, but that should be the only major issue.

Comment: numpy.linalg can just solve two equations.

Comment: Please answer your own question with whatever method you came up with. It's a nice way to help out other people who may have the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the scipy and numpy modules, scipy has the [solve()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve.html#scipy.linalg.solve) method:

```
>>> import scipy
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[3,2,0],[1,-1,0],[0,5,1]])
>>> b = np.array([2,4,-1])
>>> x = linalg.solve(a,b)
>>> x
array([ 2., -2.,  9.])
```