# Python Solving System Of Equations For Variable On Both Sides Of Equality

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

Is there a way to solve a linear system of equations in python where the unknown is on both sides of the equality. So for instance if I have:

```
x_1 = 0.7 + 0.5 * x_1 - 0.4 * x_2
x_2 = 0.7 * x_1 + 0.5 - 0.4 * x_1
x_3 = 0.7 * x_2 + 0.5 * x_1 - 0.4
```

where this can be expressed as:

```
|x_1|   | 1   x_1  x_2|| 0.7|
|x_2| = |x_1   1   x_1|| 0.5|
|x_3|   |x_2  x_1   1 ||-0.4|
```

where the we have a [Toeplitz Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix).

I could easily solve such an expression by hand, but it gets laborious as I have large sets. I was looking at

[Is there a python module to solve linear equations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789927/is-there-a-python-module-to-solve-linear-equations)

[How to solve a pair of nonlinear equations using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739227/how-to-solve-a-pair-of-nonlinear-equations-using-python)

and the [SymPy Solvers](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html) modules, but I can't seem to find a way of going about this.

Comment: If you're trying to solve matrix multiplication or system of linear equasions you can do it like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789927/is-there-a-python-module-to-solve-linear-equations or use scipy http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/linalg.html

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about what comes after "where this can be expressed as", multiplying the matrix and vector gives for example `x_1 = 0.5 + 0.7 *  x_1 - 0.4 * x_2` for the first row which does not correspond to the original equations.

Comment: @dmitryro, I've had a look at that question and those packages, it doesn't seem to apply since in those cases the matrix is composed entirely of values.

Comment: You can give a try Theano to create your initial notation and then solve it using one of the packages. http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html

Comment: For SymPy you should look at `linsolve`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get your equations to form (x_3 omitted for obvious reasons)

```
0.5 * x1 + 0.4 * x2 = 0.7
0.7 * x1 - 1.4 * x2 = -0.5
```

before you can use `numpy.linalg.solve`, like in this case

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0.5, 0.4],    # first row  x_i factors
              [0.7, -1.4]])  # second row x_i factors
b = np.array([0.7, -0.5])

sol = np.linalg.solve(a, b)

print sol
```

which gives

```
[ 0.79591837  0.75510204]
```

If the question is about how to transform the input

```
x_1 = 0.7 + 0.5 * x_1 - 0.4 * x_2
x_2 = 0.7 * x_1 + 0.5 - 0.4 * x_2
```

automatically to the form where constants are on the right side of the equations, it can be archieved by noting first that

```
0 + 1 * x_1 + 0 * x_2 = 0.7 + 0.5 * x_1 - 0.4 * x_2
0 + 0 * x_1 + 1 * x_2 = 0.5 + 0.7 * x_1 - 0.4 * x_2
```

and then placing those values in matrixes

```
import numpy as np

left = np.matrix([[0, 1, 0],    # [cons., x_1, x_2]
                  [0, 0, 1]])
right = np.matrix([[0.7, 0.5, -0.4],
                   [0.5, 0.7, -0.4]])

tmp = left - right
constants = - tmp[:, 0]
factors = tmp[:, [1, 2]]

sol = np.linalg.solve(factors, constants)

print factors
print constants
print sol
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that can be easily cast as a linear equation problem:

```
-0.7 = (0.5 - 1) * x_1 - 0.4 * x_2
-0.5 = 0.7 * x_1 - (0.4 + 1) * x_2
0.4 = 0.7 * x_2 + 0.5 * x_1 - x_3

A = np.array([[0.5-1, -0.4, 0], [0.7, -.4-1, 0], [.5, .7, -1]])
F = np.array([-.7, -.5, .4])

F = A * X
X = F/A
```

which can be solved, in most cases, with

```
np.linalg.solve(A, F)
```

If my guess is right, what is the problem?

Comment: That solves this particular example. I'm looking for something that can be done an a more general scale, and not just a 3 system equation. Also the number of equation varies from problem to problem.