# How I can get semimagic square?

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, linear-algebra

How do I implement this in Python?

> Given is an input matrix like this one:
>
> ```
> ┌───┬───┬───┐
> │ 2 │ 2 │ 5 │
> ├───┼───┼───┤
> │ . │ . │ 0 │
> ├───┼───┼───┤
> │ 3 │ . │ . │
> └───┴───┴───┘
> ```
>
> Instead of dots, insert numbers so that the sum of the numbers in the rows and columns in the square is the same.

My code:

```py
def EnterMatr():
    matr = []

    n = int(input("Enter n: "))

    print("Enter a matrix:")
    for i in range(n):
        arr = input().split()
        for j in range(len(arr)):
            if arr[j] == ".": # Dots are replaced by None
                arr[j] = None
            else:
                arr[j] = int(arr[j])
        matr.append(arr)

    return matr
    
def SimpleMatrix(number, row, colum, size):
    """
    Distribution of the matrix by elements, for example
    our matrix:
     [2 2 5]
     [. . 0]
     [1 . .]
     for 2 in (0,0) => [2 0 0]
                       [0 2 0]
                       [0 0 2]
    for 2 in (0,1) =>  [0 2 0]
                       [2 0 0]
                       [0 0 2]
    """
    matrix = [[0 for _ in range(size)] for _ in range(size)]
    matrix[row][colum] = number

    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            if not (i == row or j == colum) and RowAndColumEmpty(matrix, i, j):
                matrix[i][j] = number
                break

    return matrix

def GenerateMultiSemiMetrix(matr):
    MultiMatrix = []

    for i in range(len(matr)):
        for j in range(len(matr)):
            if matr[i][j]:
                MultiMatrix.append(SimpleMatrix(matr[i][j], i,j,len(matr)))
    return MultiMatrix

def RowAndColumEmpty(matr, row, colum):
    """
    Checking whether the row and column where we insert are empty
    """
    for i in range(len(matr)):
        if not matr[row][i] == 0:
            return False
    for i in range(len(matr)):
        if not matr[i][colum] == 0:
            return False
    return True

def addMatr(first, second):
    matrix = [[0 for _ in range(len(first))] for _ in range(len(first))]

    for i in range(len(first)):
        for j in range(len(first)):
            matrix[i][j] = first[i][j] + second[i][j]
    return matrix

def SumMatrix(MatrArr):
    matrix = [[0 for _ in range(len(MatrArr[0]))] for _ in range(len(MatrArr[0]))]
    
    for elem in MatrArr:
        matrix = addMatr(matrix, elem)
    return matrix




matr = EnterMatr()
matr = SumMatrix(GenerateMultiSemiMetrix(matr))
for elem in matr:
    print(elem)
```

Here is the output of an execution of that code:

```
Enter n: 3
Enter a matrix:
2 2 5
. . 0
1 . .
[2, 3, 5]
[7, 2, 1]
[1, 5, 4]
```

The problem is that the result matrix has different numbers at places where already numbers were given in the input matrix:

- The original 2 at (0, 1) becomes 3
- The original 0 at (1, 2) becomes 1

This should not be possible.

How can I change the program such that it would only change the dots?

Is there any algorithm or something else that could solve my problem?

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Type the text.

Comment: The only function you're asking about is the `EnterMatr` function right? If so, all of your other functions are just distractions to people who might be able to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be represented as a set of equations on the ² variables of the x matrix and a variable for the sum. Then remains to solve this set of linear equations. You can use [a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789927/is-there-a-python-module-to-solve-linear-equations) for that.

Here I have implemented the [Guassian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) method:

```
def gaussian_elimination(table):
    height = len(table)
    width = len(table[0])
    h = 0
    for x in range(width):
        abspivot = max(abs(table[y][x]) for y in range(h, height))
        if abspivot:
            pivoty = next(y for y in range(h, height) if abs(table[y][x]) == abspivot)
            pivotrow = table[pivoty]
            pivot = pivotrow[x]
            table[h], table[pivoty] = pivotrow, table[h]  # swap rows
            for j in range(x, width):  # divide pivot row to get a 1
                pivotrow[j] /= pivot
            for y, row in enumerate(table):  # subtract pivotrow from other rows
                if y != h:
                    coeff = row[x]
                    row[x] = 0
                    for j in range(x + 1, width):
                        row[j] -= coeff * pivotrow[j] 
            h += 1
            if h >= height:
                break
    # Extract the resolved values from the table
    values = [0] * (width - 1)
    for row in table:
        for i in range(width - 1):
            if row[i]:
                values[i] = row[-1]
                break
    return values
        
    
def solve(matr):
    width = len(matr)
    size = width * width
    # Create an augemented matrix representing equations
    table = []
    # Add equations to reflect sum of rows
    for y in range(width):
        eq = [0] * (size + 2)
        eq[y * width:(y+1) * width] = [1] * width
        eq[size] = -1
        table.append(eq)
    # Add equations to reflect sum of columns
    for x in range(width):
        eq = [0] * (size + 2)
        for i in range(x, size, width):
            eq[i] = 1
        eq[size] = -1
        table.append(eq)
    # Add equations to reflect the known values
    for y, row in enumerate(matr):
        for x, val in enumerate(row):
            if val is not None:
                eq = [0] * (size + 2)
                eq[y * width + x] = 1
                eq[-1] = val
                table.append(eq)
    # Solve this set of equations with the Gaussian elimination method
    values = gaussian_elimination(table)
    # Verify that all resolved values are integers
    if any(val - int(val) for val in values):
        raise ValueError("Unexpected non-integer in solution")
    values = list(map(int, values))
    # Turn the values back into a matrix
    return [ 
        values[width * y: width * (y + 1)]
        for y in range(width)
    ]
    
matr = [
    [2, 2, 5],
    [None, None, 0],
    [1, None, None]
]
print(solve(matr))
```

This outputs:

```
[[2, 2, 5], [6, 3, 0], [1, 4, 4]]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for a 4x4 matrix

Comment: Which 4x4 matrix have you tried with?

Comment: [1,2,3,7],
[1,None,None,None],
[None,None,1,None],
[1,None,1,None]

Comment: I applied a fix. Can you check?

Comment: Yes, I will be very grateful